# How can i remove this white space?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm tring to create a sidebar and navbar . Here is my screenshoot  (Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2 )

[image]

There is `#sidebarCollapse` (fa-lists icon)

so when i click it my sidebar and navbar is resizing . Here is the screenshoot

[image]

As you can see there is `white gap` between my navbar and sidebar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('full');
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  background: #7386D5;
  width: 82%;
  float: right;
}

.navbar.full {
  background: #7386D5;
  width: 94%;
  float: right;
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

i,
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
  margin-right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
  padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
#sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e259';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e260';
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
  a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
  #sidebar .CTAs {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a span {
    font-size: 0.85em;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  #sidebar ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a i {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <a id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></a>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
    <h3>Sidebar</h3>
    <strong>SB</strong>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-unstyled components">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
      </a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> About
      </a>
      <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-clone"></i> Pages
      </a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-link"></i> Portfolio
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> FAQ
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How i can remove the white space there ? My Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uepymjen/1/

Comment: I think the code you posted is not enough to understand where the problem is...

Comment: The problem you've got is that `.sidebar` has a width sized in pixels but `.navbar` has a width defined in percent. Unless the window is exactly the right size they are unlikely to be aligned as you wish.

Comment: @ChristophBühler i'm using google chrome .

Comment: @YVS1102 never mind, phuzi is right. You should not use percent. General rule: Don't use percent if you can avoid it.